# How do I add a string to a vector using a function?

Tags: c++, string, vector

How do I add a string to a vector using a function?

Comment: Read about [passing by reference](stackoverflow.com/questions/373419)

Comment: @Blake Collins is obviously one of my students who wants his homework taken care of (this is his homework for the week).  Can this post be removed? The class has its own discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

Any operation that modifies the list should pass the list **by reference**, otherwise it is just modifying a **copy** of the original list. I.e.

```
void AddToList(vector<string>& List){
```

The `&` indicates that `AddToList` is taking a reference to the original list, not a copy of the original list.

This is what's happening in your case. You are adding an item to a copy of the list, but the original list is still empty. Then you try to access the last item of an empty list, and your program crashes.

Comment: So for all functions where I modify said List, I need to pass the list by reference. When I just want to access the list, I don't need to add an ampersand?

Comment: @BlakeCollins, You can do that but the more efficient method would be to pass by `const&`.